# Is $R_k = \left\{\frac{a+b\sqrt{k}}{2}: a, b \in \mathbb Z, \text{both even or both odd}\right\}$ closed under multiplication? What if $k = -3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $$\color{blue}{R = \left\{\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}: a, b \in \mathbb Z, a \text{ and } b \text{ both even or both odd}\right\}}$$ Is $R$ a commutative ring with identity? Is it an integral domain? Identify $R^\times$, the group of units of $R$.
>
> Source: *Algebra in Action: A Course in Groups, Rings, and Fields* by Shahriar Shahriari.

**My work**:
I have checked that $(R, +)$ is an abelian group and that multiplication is associative. The distributive laws hold, since they hold in $\mathbb C$. To check if $R$ is an integral domain, suppose $$\left(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{c+d\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) = \frac{ac - 3bd+(bc + ad)\sqrt{-3}}{4} = 0$$
so that $ac =  3bd$ and $bc = -ad$. This means $abc = 3b^2d = -a^2d$ giving $(3b^2 + a^2)d = 0$. So, $a = b = 0$ or $d = 0$. If $a = b = 0$, then we're good. If $d = 0$, then $bc = 0$ and $ac = 0$. Either $c = 0$ or $a = b = 0$ - in any case, $R$ is an integral domain.

---

> Q$1$. I need to check that $R$ is closed under multiplication.

$$\left(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{c+d\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) = \frac{ac - 3bd+(bc + ad)\sqrt{-3}}{4}$$
We've to make three cases here: (i) $a,b$ even and $c,d$ even (ii) $a,b$ even and $c,d$ odd (iii) $a,b$ odd and $c,d$ odd. Then, I will have to check whether $\frac{ac-3bd}{2}$ and $\frac{bc + ad}{2}$ are even or odd, in each case. Is there a **shorter** way to do this?

$\color{teal}{\text{Answered by Bill Dubuque}}$ in the comments: $$\bmod 4\!:\ \underbrace{ac+bd}_{\large ac\,-3\,bd}-(bc+ad) = (a-b)(c-d)\equiv 0$$
so $\frac{ac-3bd}{2}$ and $\frac{bc + ad}{2}$ are both even or both odd.

---

> Q$2$. How do we find $R^\times$?

Suppose $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2} \in R^\times$, so $a\ne 0$ or $b\ne 0$. Then,
$$\left(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{c+d\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) = \frac{ac - 3bd+(bc + ad)\sqrt{-3}}{4} = 1$$ implies $ac - 3bd = 4$ and $bc = -ad$. Solving, we have $d = \frac{-4b}{a^2 + 3b^2}$ and $c = \frac{4a}{a^2 + 3b^2}$. However, I'm not sure when $c,d$ are **integers**.

---

> Q$3$. Is there anything special about $\sqrt{-3}$? When can I expect that $$\color{blue}{R_k = \left\{\frac{a+b\sqrt{k}}{2}: a, b \in \mathbb Z, a \text{ and } b \text{ both even or both odd }\right\}}$$ is a ring? an integral domain? Here, $k$ is a square-free non-negative integer (possibly negative).

I have observed the following if $d \equiv 1\bmod 4$. Take $\xi = \frac{a+ b\sqrt{d}}{2} \in R_{d}$ where $d = 4m + 1$ for some $m\in \Bbb Z$. Then, $$\xi^2 = \frac{\frac{a^2 + b^2d}{2} + ab\sqrt{d}}{2} \in R_d$$

If $a, b$ both are even, then $a = 2k_1$ and $b = 2k_2$ for some $k_1,k_2\in \Bbb Z$. We see that $\frac{a^2 + b^2d}{2} = 2k_1^2 + 2k_2^2d$ is even, and $ab = 4k_1k_2$ is also even. If $a,b$ both are odd, then $a = 2k_1 + 1$ and $b = 2k_2 + 1$ for some $k_1,k_2\in \Bbb Z$. We see that $\frac{a^2 + b^2d}{2} = \frac{4k_1^2 + 4k_1 + 4k_2^2d + 4k_2d + d + 1}{2} = 2k_1^2 + 2k_1 + 2k_2^2d + 2k_2d + 2m + 1$ is odd, and $ab = 4k_1k_2 + 2(k_1 + k_2) + 1$ is also odd.

---

*A note on definitions:*

1. An integral domain is a commutative ring $R$ with unity, with $|R| \ge 2$ and no zero divisors.

Comment: For Q2, $(c+d\sqrt{-3})/2$ has to have integers $c$ and $d$. Wait, you've deleted the part about units. For the new Q2, take $k=-1$, or $k=3$, and see whether it's closed under multiplication.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right, I did not verify that $c,d$ are integers. How does that work? Let me bring the question back to the way it was.

Comment: Q1: $\bmod 2\!:\,\ a\equiv b,\, c\equiv d\Rightarrow ac-3bd\equiv bd-bd\equiv 0,\,$ and $\,bc+ad\equiv bd+bd\equiv 0\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I think we want to do the calculations $\bmod 4$? Your computation only tells me that $\frac{ac-3bd}{2}$ and $\frac{bc + ad}{2}$ are integers. I need to ensure that, $\bmod 2$, $$\frac{ac-3bd}{2} \equiv \frac{bc + ad}{2}$$

Comment: Further hint: $\bmod 4\!:\ \underbrace{ac+bd}_{\large ac\,-3\,bd}-(bc+ad) = (a-b)(c-d)\equiv 0\ $ by $\,2\mid a-b,\, c-d\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks a lot! That essentially completes the proof.

Comment: OK, so now there's still Q3, where my comment  about $k=-1$ and $k=3$ applies.

Comment: Have you lost interest in Q3, delta?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Of course, not! It is the most interesting one after all. I have been trying to see what happens when $k = -1$ or $k = 3$ - but I haven't found anything useful yet. Not sure how to go about it. Besides, Q2 is pending too.

Comment: OK. $\alpha=(1+i)/2$ is in $R_{-1}$. Is $\alpha^2$ in $R_{-1}$? $\beta=(1+\sqrt3)/2$ is in $R_3$. Is $\beta^2$ in $R_3$?

Comment: $\alpha^2 \notin R_{-1}$ and $\beta^2 \notin R_3$. How do you generalize from here? It seems $R_{-3}$ is special in some sense. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Now, try $R_5$. Let $\gamma=(1+\sqrt5)/2$. It's in $R_5$. Is $\gamma^2$? Can you see why some work, and some don't?

Comment: @GerryMyerson If $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then if $\xi = \frac{a+ b\sqrt{d}}{2} \in R_{d}$ we have $\xi^2 \in R_d$ also. This is what I have observed. What do you think?

Comment: And if $d$ isn't $1\bmod4$, and $\xi=(a+b\sqrt d)/2$ with $a,b$ both odd, then $\xi^2$ is not in $R_d$. Good observation! Can you prove it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I just have to produce a suitable $\xi$ for the same. Sorry for the late response. By the way, I realized that my work is not enough in the $d\equiv 1\bmod 4$ case. I would have to show for any $\xi_1,\xi_2\in R_d$, that $\xi_1\xi_2\in R_d$. I did only the special case $\xi_1 = \xi_2$. Thoughts?

Comment: @delta-divine The proof when $d \equiv 1\bmod 4$ is almost the same as 
Bill Dubuque's comment.

Comment: @Zerox Could you elaborate?